# Is there any way to make some words (only some words not whole editor) in Rad editor for Ajax read only?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, readonly, radeditor, telerik-editor

I am using Telerik Rad Editor for Ajax in my project,I want to make some fields/words read only. I tried couple of things and it's working for whole editor.. meaning whole editor becomes read only. I just want some words and rest of the editor as it is to edit for users. Is it possible ? which property to set ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is ASP.Net project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to define editable and non-editable regions in RadEditor, you should place several DIV or SPAN element containers in the editor content area. After that, set the unselectable="on" attribute to their tags in order to prohibit selection of these elements. You should also set the contentEditable attribute to "false" to put these elements in non-editable mode.

Example: Adding editable and non-editable areas in RadEditor.

```
<div style="border: red 1px solid;" contenteditable="false" unselectable="on">
    Non Editable AREA
    <div style="border: green 1px solid;" contenteditable="true" unselectable="off">
        <!--Content name="info" -->
        Editable REGION...
        <!--/Content -->
    </div>
    Non Editable AREA
</div>
```